# Pytorch tensor to numpy gives "()" as shape

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

I have a pytorch tensor

`span_end = tensor([[[13]]])`

I do the following

```py
span_end = span_end.view(1).squeeze().data.numpy()
            print(type(span_end))
            print(span_end.shape)
```

This gives me the following output

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
()
```

Then later when I try to access the `0th` element of `span_end` I get `IndexError` because the shape is null somehow. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tensor.squeeze()` will remove all dimensions of size 1, which in this case all of them are therefore it will result in a tensor with no dimensions.

Removing that statement will work.

```py
import torch
span_end = torch.tensor([[[13]]])
span_end = span_end.view(1).numpy()
print(type(span_end))
print(span_end.shape)
print(span_end[0])
```

Outputs:

```py
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
(1,)
13
```